# create .exe file which takes parameters, generates and executes SQL queries, SSMS 2005

Tags: exe, ssms

I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2005 to write the scripts I use on a database. Other people using the same database can query it, but do not have SMSS and cannot execute multiple batches at once, which is very limiting.

I'd like to be able to create .exe files which I can give to other users, which would basically be simple bush-buttons. They would prompt for certain parameters and inject them into my script, then run it. I am told I could do this if I had Visual Management studio, but alas, I do not.

Is there any way to do this with just SSMS (and anything else as long as it's free) Or do I absolutely have to buy more software? I'm willing to use whatever programming language will get it done.

Answer (score 0):

Get your hands on one of the [Express editions of Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express) - they're free and perfectly suited to what you're wanting to do.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know whether I need to go and find visual studio express 2005 edition, or will the 2010 version work with server management 2005? I'm on Windows 7.

Comment: I don't think it's important that it work with SSMS 2005 - more important is that 2010 will work against all versions of SQL Server - and it will.